# Create a CheckList using Trello.Net Edge

Tags: trello.net

I am trying to create a checkList, but it throws an exception with this description: "invalid value for idCard"
this is the code that i am using:

```
var checkList = trello.Checklists.Add("My CheckList", b);
```

my doubt is why it throws an exception for idCard but there is no way to specify one in the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue.

Here is a work around:

dynamic mychecklist = trello.Advanced.Post("/checklists", new {  idCard = CardID, name = CheckList.Name, idChecklistSource = CheckList.Id} );

Comment: dillenmeister - had this example set up gave a good reference// If you need to call the trello api in a way that Trello.NET does not support, you can issue a custom request. 
    // Look at the API reference https://trello.com/docs/api/index.html
    // This example gets a list and all it's cards in the same request
    dynamic myList = trello.Advanced.Get("/lists/1234567890abcdefghijklmn", new { cards = "all" });
    Console.WriteLine(myList.name);
    foreach (var card in myList.cards)
        Console.WriteLine(card.name);

Comment: Please could you fix the post's formatting, and include this additional information in the main post? You can click "edit", preview your post and check out the help section for the various formatting options.